# Loop Index automatically updated in the middle of Iteration

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

Please take a look at this simple data frame:

`1     4      a
 2      5      b
 3      6      c
 4      7      d
 5      8      e
 6      9       f
 7     10     g`

Ignore the third column for now. I would like to create a fourth column with a binary variable that would signal that specific row is a continuation of a previous one.

Let me illustrate,

`1     4       a       1
 2      5      b       0
 3      6      c       0
 4      7      d       1
 5      8      e       0
 6      9      f        0
 7     10     g       1`

First row we start with "1 goes to 4" and this is our base, the starting point of a path.
On the next row we have "2 goes to 5", but since we are already at 4, number 2 is not a continuation, so, the fourth column gets a "0". This row is disconected with our base.
In the next row "3 goes to 6", again disconected because we are already at 4, we should restart at 4.

That's exactly what happens next... "4 goes to 7" connecting with the first row and because of that the fourth column gets a "1".
Similarly, only the row "7 goes to 10" reconnects the path and gets a "1"

Ultimately i want to filter the "1s" because the letter column has the important information. But that's easy with dplyr. Forget about it.

My failed approach went like this: I created a loop with i and j, that would search when a value in column 2 would be equal to a value in column 1, further down. The problem is for example the row "2 goes to 5" also connects with the row "5 goes to 8" and would receive a "1"

I can't see how to instruct the loop for when it finds the first connection, "4 goes 7" to use that finding as the new base. Only that way the next positive return is the row that starts with 7.

My head hurts. I hope someone with a cooler head, can show me the light.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another attempt using a simple loop in R would be:

```
x <- 1:7
y <- 4:10

largest_nr <- min(x, y) # to get a 1 in the first entry
res_vec <- c() # empty vector

# loop through the numbers and check if we have a new largest number
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
 if (min(x[i], y[i]) >= largest_nr) {
  # new largest number found
  largest_nr <- max(x[i], y[i])
  res_vec <- c(res_vec, 1)
 } else {
  # no new largest number found
  res_vec <- c(res_vec, 0)
 }
}

cbind(x, y, res_vec)
#>      x  y res_vec
#> [1,] 1  4       1
#> [2,] 2  5       0
#> [3,] 3  6       0
#> [4,] 4  7       1
#> [5,] 5  8       0
#> [6,] 6  9       0
#> [7,] 7 10       1
```

Answer (score 0):

First your dataset example:

```
dat <-
structure(list(X = 1:7, Y = 4:10, Z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "g")), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Now try the following.

```
next_one <- function(dat, curr){
    # Get the connect point from the second column
    i <- dat[curr, 2]
    # Now a vector of potential continuations
    i <- which(dat[, 1] >= i)
    # If there's a continuation, it's the first,
    #   else we're at the end of the column
    i <- if(length(i) >= 1) i[1] else 0L
    i
}

W <- integer(nrow(dat))
W[1] <- 1L
curr <- 1

while(curr <= nrow(dat)){
    i <- next_one(dat, curr)
    if(i){
        W[i] <- 1L
        curr <- i
    }else
        break
}

new_dat <- cbind(dat, W)
new_dat
  X  Y Z W
1 1  4 a 1
2 2  5 b 0
3 3  6 c 0
4 4  7 d 1
5 5  8 e 0
6 6  9 f 0
7 7 10 g 1
```

Comment: David's answer is a bit more simple, making it more versatile to test raw data. Nonetheless i'm in this for the long run so i'm thankful for your solution. I'm going to study your code carefully, in a way to show appreciation for your effort, but also to add one more trick to my knowledge. Maybe you can explain how does the "next_one" function works. It seems more advanced than basic tutorials. Btw, i can't upvote your answer because i don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: @RandomLuck Don't worry about votes, they don't impress my grandson. As for an explanation on how the function works, I'll edit my code and include comments.